# Best optimized way to set hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

i got horizontal menu with images for example like this:

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="#"><img src="http://liubavyshka.ru/_ph/17/2/862998023.gif" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://liubavyshka.ru/_ph/17/2/862998023.gif" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://liubavyshka.ru/_ph/17/2/862998023.gif" width="100" height="100"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://liubavyshka.ru/_ph/17/2/862998023.gif" width="100" height="100"></a>
</div>
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/65UYD/)

what a light weight variant of hover effect i can use to make images more noticeable on hover?

Comment: -__- define `visuality`…

Comment: You can never have enough visuality! You can google for the CSS `:hover` property.

Comment: I'm not going to down vote this, but this not a technical question.. this is more a design question..

Comment: yes it looks like design question, but I ask about technologies that are light weight and easy to use

Comment: you ask for a light weight tech to do 'something' that looks good "make more visuality" in your words... that 'something' is a design issue.

Comment: ok, sorry that take your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this, it is very simple, light, no scripts, pure css and looks good:

```
.menu img{
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: margin 0.5s ease-out;
}

.menu img:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/65UYD/1/)